# how to get new location in google places in iphone?

Tags: iphone, location, latitude-longitude, gettime

sir i am new to iPhone development. i need to know how to get new location without sending latitude and langtitude in the url request.

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search           /json?location=40.7143528,-74.0059731&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM"];
```

this is my code here i did request through url request with iat and lang values now i need to give without this two values. but it should take current values

Comment: you mean to say it should take your device lat long ???

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: yes inder kumar rathore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//These are your delegate methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //if the time interval returned from core location is more than two minutes we ignore it because it might be from an old session
    if ( abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) {     
        // Make your request here as
         NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=10000&types=school&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM",newLocation.Latitude,newLocation.Longitude];
         NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```